# How to make 2 websites use the same posts tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 2 different websites installed on the same database. The 2 websites are sharing the users tables, but I want them to share the posts tables too. I tried to do it by editing wp-db.php, using a method I found from some old posts. After this code:

```
foreach ( $this->tables( 'global' ) as $table => $prefixed_table )
$this->$table = $prefixed_table;
```

I added this code:

```
$this->posts = 'wp_' . 'posts';
$this->postmeta = 'wp' . 'postmeta';
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

I need to make both websites to use the same posts and postmeta tables instead of every site using it's own posts and postmeta tables. How can I make the 2 websites use the same posts and postmeta tables?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. But it sounds like one to resolve with your provider and/or wordpress

Comment: I need to make 2 websites that share the same database, to use the same posts and postmeta tables. Right now each one of them has it's own tables, but I want to force one of the websites to use the posts and postmeta tables of the other website.

Comment: establish 2 seperate connections? and use 1 to access the posts and postmeta tables and the 2nd one to access his own data.

Comment: Would not it be simpler to have a single wp site, and within that site you create 2 "sub-sites", rather than trying to force 2 wp instances to share the same db? See http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: I already created the 2 websites with 2 different domains and it would take a lot of work to migrate one website, map the domain etc. Besides that, [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) it says that _If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that share data, or share users, then a multisite network might not be the best solution._